# App Design Issue : android.database.StaleDataException

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-cursor, staledataexception

Firstly I have investigated other StaleDataExceptions on SO but none really answer, or lead me to a solution to my current App design problem.

I'm creating a Music Player App, which I initially designed to query the `MediaStore.Audio` with a `CursorLoader` to retrieve information from the Content Provider - this works fine, however obviously if you have a big music library there could be a more than desirable wait time getting all the information back when the app loads each time.  My second approach was to start a remote `Service` on app first launch, which queries the `MediaStore.Audio` using a `CursorLoader` and registers for any updates. When the `Cusror` is returned I then run an `AsyncTask` to process the information into an ArrayList of Custom POJO class that implements the `Parcelable Interface` which then gets marshalled/demarshalled via an `Intent` back to a handler in the Music App.  This solution works well because if the app is closed, and reopened it just queries the `Service` for the latest `ArrayList` of custom `Objects`, rather than having to query the `MediaStore.Audio` at all - the `Service` implements `LoaderCallback<Cursor>` and always updates `ArrayList` of custom `Objects` and notifies the App if open, if not it has them ready for when the app is reopened.

Right - to the problem (ok took a bit of time, but necessary background information). The issue is : If I'm in another media app and start deleting music files in quick succession the registered `Listener` in my service is calledback and a new cursor is delivered, however the `AsyncTask` I am using to iterate over the existing cursor  has a `Race Condition` where it is closed by another `Thread` / `CursorLoader` as the `Cursor` is updated - exception thrown : `android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.`

The current workaround I'm using is use `setUpdateThrottle` to 20 seconds when registering the listener, this works, however means there is a delay in getting updated information back to the Service.

Is there any viable solution or approach where I can avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

A working viable solution, was actually quite easy to achieve - it initial problem however does illustrate my lack of experience with Loaders, however I've gained some knowledge on the way to finding a solution.

*Solution:*

I am still using a remote `Service`. However instead of using a `CursorLoader` - which was closing the `cursor` whilst I was still processing it in the `onLoadComplete()` callback, I am using a `AsyncTaskLoader`.  The `AsyncTaskLoader` coupled with a `ContentObserver` can still monitor for underlying data changes from a `Uri` but is not directly coupled with the `Cursor` object like a `CursorLoader`.  I am able to monitor for data changes and let the `AsyncTaskLoader` know it needs to reload data (`forceLoad()`), however this is queued, and doesn't affect the processing of loadInBackground() method - Once this returns, it simply cancels the task and starts the new task.